# Unicode list to String list Python 2

Tags: python, string, unicode

I have this list:

```
l = [u'\xf9', u'!']
```

And I want to convert it in this list:

```
l2 = ['ù','!']
```

How can i do it? and Why does l.encode() not work?

Comment: Er, because encode is a method on strings, not on lists.

Comment: What you mean by convert? `'ù'` is just a type of representation of your character! do you mean that you want to print it like that?

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to say l[0].encode()

Comment: `[u.encode('u8') for u in l]` l[0].encode wont work because the character is outside ascii range (128)

Comment: That's what i Did Shashank, but why 'ù' is converted to '\xc3\xb9'? This should have been my question... sorry.

Comment: You could look through here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#encodings-and-unicode I tried using ISO 8859 but that gave me just a string with '\xf9' and you wanted u with grave so that's incorrect...what I tried is `u'ù'.encode('iso8859-1')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using Python 2 ? If it is the case, you might be fooled by the way Python displays strings.

As you noticed, `'\xc3\xb9'` is the UTF-8 encoded representation of code point U+00F9 (`'ù'`). So:

```
# code point
>>> u'ù'
u'\xf9'

# seems wrong ?
>>> u'ù'.encode('utf-8')
'\xc3\xb9'

# No, not at all (at least on my UTF-8 terminal)
>>> print(u'ù'.encode('utf-8'))
ù
```

Given your example:

```
>>> l = [u'\xf9', u'!']
>>> print(l)
[u'\xf9', u'!']
>>> l[0]
u'\xf9'
>>> print(l[0])
ù

>>> l2 = [u.encode('utf-8') for u in l]
>>> l2
['\xc3\xb9', '!']
>>> print(l2)
['\xc3\xb9', '!']
>>> print(l2[0])
ù
```

I agree all of this is [rather inconsistent and source of frustration](https://pythonhosted.org/kitchen/unicode-frustrations.html). That's why string/unicode support was a major rewrite in Python 3. There:

```
# Python 3
>>> l = [u'\xf9', u'!']
>>> l
['ù', '!']
```